# Status Update does not show on the stored scheduledDateTime

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='updateType']").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "scheduled") {
        $("#scheduleForm").show();
      } else {
        $("#scheduleForm").hide();
      }
    });

    $("#statusChangeForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var selectedStatus = $("#statusSelect").val();
      var updateType = $("input[name='updateType']:checked").val();
      var scheduleDate = $("#datePicker").val();
      var scheduleTime = $("#timePicker").val();
      var repeatStatus = $("input[name='repeatStatus']:checked").val();

      // Get the current timestamp using JavaScript
      var currentDateTime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");

      $.ajax({
        url: "my-whereabouts-update-status.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          status: selectedStatus,
          updateType: updateType,
          scheduleDate: scheduleDate,
          scheduleTime: scheduleTime,
          repeatStatus: repeatStatus,
          currentDateTime: currentDateTime // Include current timestamp in the data
        },
        success: function(response) {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Success',
            text: response,
            icon: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
              location.reload();
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'An error occurred. Please try again.',
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
          });
        }
      });
    });

    $(".scheduled-update").each(function() {
      var updateType = $(this).data("update-type");
      var scheduledDateTime = new Date($(this).data("scheduled-timestamp")); // Get the scheduled date and time as a DateTime object
      var currentDateTime = new Date(); // Get the current date and time as a DateTime object

      if (updateType === "scheduled") {
        if (currentDateTime.getTime() === scheduledDateTime.getTime()) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      } else {
        $(this).hide(); // Instant updates should always be shown
      }
    });

  });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Jost';
    background-color: #f0f4fc;
  }
  .card {
    border-radius: 17px; /* Adjust the value as per your preference */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1); /* Adjust the shadow properties as per your preference */
  }
  .navbar {
    background: #28382b;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item a.nav-link {
    color: #ffffff; /* Change to the default color */
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Add a smooth transition */
  }

  .navbar-nav .nav-item a.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff; /* Change to the desired hover color */
    transform: scale(1.05); /* Expand slightly on hover */
  }

  .navbar-brand img {
    opacity: 1; /* Reset opacity to 1 by default */
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Add a smooth transition */
  }

  .navbar-brand:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4; /* Adjust opacity as desired */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Status System</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>



  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVBAR -->



<div class="container pl-3 pr-3  ">
    <h1 class="mt-3 "><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Status</h1>
    <h6 class="mb-4 small">You can view your latest status or change it here.</h6>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $profileQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT profilePicture FROM tblAccount WHERE email = '$email'");
    $profileData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileQuery);
    $profilePicture = $profileData['profilePicture'];
    ?>
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="profile-picture mr-3" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid <?php echo ($currentStatusID == 1) ? 'green' : (($currentStatusID == 6) ? 'red' : 'orange'); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo ($profilePicture) ? $profilePicture : 'pic/dummy.jpg'; ?>" class="rounded-circle" width="80" height="80" alt="Profile Picture">
            </div>

            <div>
                <h5 class="card-title">Current Status</h5>
                <p class="card-text" id="currentStatusText"><strong><?php echo $currentStatus; ?></strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
    // Loop through the status updates and display them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $statusID = $row['statusID'];
        $statusCode = $row['statusCode'];
        $scheduledDateTime = strtotime($row['scheduledDateTime']);
        $updateType = $row['updateType'];
        
        // Determine whether to display the status update or not
        $displayStyle = ($updateType === "instant") ? "display: block;" : "display: none;";
        if ($updateType === "scheduled" && time() >= $scheduledDateTime) {
            $displayStyle = "display: block;";
        }
        ?>
        <div class="scheduled-update" style="<?php echo $displayStyle; ?>"
             data-scheduled-timestamp="<?php echo $scheduledDateTime; ?>"
             data-update-type="<?php echo $updateType; ?>"
        >
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Scheduled Update</h5>
                <p class="card-text"><strong><?php echo $statusCode; ?></strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Change Status</h5>
            <form id="statusChangeForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="statusSelect">Select Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="statusSelect" name="status">
                        <?php
                        // Loop through the status list and generate the dropdown options
                        foreach ($statusList as $statusID => $statusCode) {
                            echo "<option value='$statusID'>$statusCode</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Status Update Type:</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="updateType" value="instant" checked> Instant Update<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="updateType" value="scheduled"> Scheduled Update
                </div>
                <div id="scheduleForm" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Add your scheduling form inputs here -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datePicker">Select Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datePicker" name="scheduleDate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="timePicker">Select Time:</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="timePicker" name="scheduleTime">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Repeat Status Each Day:</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="repeatStatus" value="yes"> Yes<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="repeatStatus" value="no"> No
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Confirm Status</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</div>
```

I'm creating a school assignment on storing two types of updates (instant or scheduled). Instant update does not need to have a scheduledDateTime but it stores the timestamp on mySQL since the code relies on the scheduledDateTime which of the status updates is the latest. It works for an instant update, but not for a scheduled update. Every time I tried to update a status with schedule, the code treated the scheduled update like an instant update, which is why it shows instantly instead of showing it on the scheduled date and time stored on scheduledDateTime.

My DB table tblStatusUpdate has this columns:

[image]

I tried to modify the php code and js code and add conditional statement: if the currentDateTime is greater than or equal to scheduledDateTime, the status will show. But it still treats the scheduled update as instant update.

js

```
$(".scheduled-update").each(function() {
      var updateType = $(this).data("update-type");
      var scheduledDateTime = new Date($(this).data("scheduled-timestamp")); // Get the scheduled date and time as a DateTime object
      var currentDateTime = new Date(); // Get the current date and time as a DateTime object

      if (updateType === "scheduled") {
        if (currentDateTime.getTime() === scheduledDateTime.getTime()) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      } else {
        $(this).hide(); // Instant updates should always be shown
      }
    });
```

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit();
}

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE email='$email'");

if ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  if ($result['accountTypeID'] === '3') {
    header('Location: index.php');
  } else{
    //NADA/NONE/WALA 
  } 
}

// Fetch the list of available status options
$statusQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT statusID, statusCode FROM tblStatus");
if (!$statusQuery) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$statusList = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statusQuery)) {
  $statusList[$row['statusID']] = $row['statusCode'];
}

// PANG RETRIEVE NG CURRENT STATUS
// PANG RETRIEVE NG CURRENT STATUS
$currentStatus = '';
$currentStatusID = '';

// Get the current status from the latest status update
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT su.statusID, s.statusCode, su.updateType, su.scheduledDateTime
                            FROM tblStatusUpdate su
                            INNER JOIN tblStatus s ON su.statusID = s.statusID
                            WHERE su.userID = (SELECT userID FROM tblAccount WHERE email='$email')
                            ORDER BY su.scheduledDateTime DESC
                            LIMIT 1");

if (!$query) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$currentUpdateType = "instant"; // Default value for update type
$scheduledDateTime = null; // Default value for scheduled date and time

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  if (isset($row['statusID']) && isset($row['statusCode'])) {
    $currentStatus = $row['statusCode'];
    $currentStatusID = $row['statusID']; // Set the current status ID
    $currentUpdateType = $row['updateType']; // Get the update type
    $scheduledDateTime = new DateTime($row['scheduledDateTime']); // Convert scheduled timestamp to DateTime
  }
}

// JavaScript code to display status updates
echo '<script>';
echo 'var currentUpdateType = "' . $currentUpdateType . '";'; // Pass the update type to JavaScript
echo 'var scheduledDateTime = ' . json_encode($scheduledDateTime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')) . ';'; // Pass the scheduled DateTime to JavaScript
echo '</script>';





//FOR POSTING ITO
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    $selectedStatusID = $_POST['status'];

    // Get the userID of the logged-in user
    $userID = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT userID FROM tblAccount WHERE email='$email'"))['userID'];

    // Insert the new status update into tblStatusUpdate
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblStatusUpdate (userID, statusID, scheduledDateTime) VALUES ('$userID', '$selectedStatusID', NOW())";

    
    if (mysqli_query($con, $insertQuery)) {
      // Update the current status display
      $currentStatus = $statusList[$selectedStatusID];
      echo "Status update stored successfully.";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
  }
}

?>
```

This is the whole webpage code:
https://pastecode.io/s/kgiz5isq

Looking forward to your insights.

Comment: Is this a PHP or a JS problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, can you share more details, like the HTML markup and the PHP code, if they are relevant?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @NicoHaase i don't know if it is JS or PHP code. I tried to use Unix timestamp first since I thought it is the problem. I remember using Unix timestamp on that same webpage to store scheduledDateTime but the timestamp it store is not the same as the device's date and time. The device is in 08-28-23 but it stored 08-27-23. Since then, I change the unix timestamp to currentDateTime of Javascript

Comment: @mplungjan I already added the code snippet here

Comment: If you don't know whether this is a PHP or a JS problem, please start debugging. Does the request that is sent to the server contain the expected data? Is the server able to read that data properly, and handle it properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase i already start debugging since I created that webpage. I don't have problems storing the data to the database as well as fetching it (the status, the account details, etc.). My only problem is the fetching the scheduled status on its scheduled date and time. There is no problem with storing the status (thru server code) and its fetching as well as the ORDER of the latest update. I say that I don't know whether it is PHP or js because there is no error shown. I even tried to add console log just to sure if the code gets the currentDateTime by showing it on the console, still no use

Comment: @NicoHaase I already include it

Comment: Please be warned that the SQL queries that you've shared are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase i'll include it when I'm done in this webpage